# Moving files from Azure Blob / Files storage to Azure FTP space

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, azure-storage-files

Would like to know whether it is a feasible to move the folder ( with files ) from Azure blob/file storage to webapp root.

***Scenario***: Would like to replace gallery of images folder used by static HTML site for gallery section weekly using powershell.

Request suggestions or alternatives as not sure how to handle this in azure and schedule swapping of folders between blob and ftp.

Comment: Note: The above request is because FTP is not preferred for creative team. so do not prefer to grant FTP access and prefers to route via Azure storage. once on Azure storage, script shall move folder and overwrite on azure webapp ftp space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BlobTrigger trigger with WebJob](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to/) deployed on the same web app and copy the files from blob storage to the local file system.

Comment: But, one gap I found evaluating Functions is that API events are at file level. Would CloudBlobDirectory or sub directory creation trigger or only blob CRUD operations alone would trigger? Added, would the trigger expect the destination to have the directory pre-existing?

Comment: I mean, say storageaccount name = "GlobalStorageAccount" got a container "Galleries" within which I got folders "Gallery 1" with files in it. Now, when I upload a new folder "Gallery 2" with subfolders + images in it, would blob trigger function. Would this "Gallery 2" folder could be created?

Answer (score 1):

> Would like to replace gallery of images folder used by static HTML site for gallery section weekly using powershell.

Please try to store the images in Azure blob directly. We can access the images in Azure blob with 'Full public read access' mode or 'Public read access for blobs only' mode. Refer to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-manage-access-to-resources/) for more details. Then we can use Scheduler Webjob to replace the images directly.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear to me exactly what you are trying to do. If you have a legacy app / adoption of FTP you can mount an FTP server on Azure File Storage. Or alternatively Blob Storage can be used for public data as described above. If you want a simple tool for interacting with Blob Storage then you can try [Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/).